# Nodelets And Desynchronized Images

Tags: ros, camera, nodelet, primesense, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

Can too many desynchronized images cause a camera_nodelet to crash?
For one of my programs I have a camera_nodelet publishing all my images, but when it crashes, I always get a few "Image desynchronised" when the nodelet is about to crashing. I get a few of those messages, then, bamm!...it crashes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248594/nodelets-and-desynchronized-images/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's possible, I suppose. Hard to tell based on the information you provide.

If you do enough debugging to narrow things down to a specific component, please open a bug report on the failing package's repository. Be sure to provide as much information as possible on how to reproduce the problem, and any information you gained while tracking it down.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0